# Applet Image Cache

Tags: java, image, caching, applet

I have an applet that shows a couple of images. A lot (10-20) of these images is identical, and is fetched from the internet in a non-parallel way. Is there an imagecache that I can use? So I only fetch the same image once, or do I have to make my own?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much depends on your needs, but I'm guessing you want a minimal footprint in an Applet. This very simple [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/googleolympiad) uses a `List` implementation to cache images by index. To ease making the list circular, the same index is used in a parallel list of names. In your case, a suitable `Map<String, Image>` implementation might be simpler. If memory is tight, [`LinkedHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) can be used as a [*Simple (LRU) Cache in Java*](http://littletechsecrets.wordpress.com/2008/11/16/simple-lru-cache-in-java/).